# Building a tower defense game. How do I add a circular menu with tower choices on tile Node in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, sprite, sprite-kit

I'm building a tower defence game using SpriteKit and I'm relatively new to this.
My map basically consists of tile Nodes that are touchable. Once a user touches the node, I can place a tower on that node (I have this part working so far). What I want to do moving forward, is instead of directly placing a tower, I'd like a circular menu to pop up around the tile Node to let the user pick the tower that they wish to place in this tile node.If the user clicks anywhere other than the circular menu, the menu should disappear.

So something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs7eu.jpg

I'm wondering what the best way to do this is. I have two possible solutions but they seem hacky:

1) Creating a custom UIView consisting of the menu and 4 buttons and then adding it to my scene (but then how do I detect button presses in this menu from the scence?)

2) Extending a SKShapeNode to create a circle and adding in 4 SpriteNodes around the circle, then verifying if a touch location corresponds to one of the 4 SpriteNode locations.

Any suggestions/code examples of how best to approach this?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you create a separate class for your tile nodes (which inherit SKSpriteNode) and add the functionality within that.

For the approach for the menu, I think something along the lines of point (2) would be better. By subclassing the tile node, you can make the tile detect the selection by itself.

1. Expand the tile using SKShapeNode or a SKSpriteNode with a circular image using animation.
2. Place the four buttons on the expanded part.
3. Implement the touch for the selection within the tile node class.

For closing the menu, a tap on the scene can trigger a NSNotification for which the tileNode could become a listener on expansion.